# Javascript nested object recursive

Tags: javascript, object, recursion, nested

So ,i did my research and so far i cannot find any good solution to my problem...

so i have an object approach so i have tried a recursive function but it doesnt work at all
(why i am here)

this function go thru one layer and stops she finds that id 3 , id 11 have both 1 childrens , while i want it to go deeper

i hope it is not a duplicate post

and i thank you in advance

#function

```
const haveChild = (obj, parent_id=0) =>{
        for (const [key,value] of Object.entries(obj)){
            if (value && typeof value === "object"){
                if (value['childrens']){
                    for (const [k,v] of Object.entries(value.childrens)){
                        haveChild(v,v.parent_id)
                        console.log('-----',v.name,'parent id= ',v.parent_id)

                    }
                }else{

                }
            }

        }
```

#data from API

```
{ 
    "2": {
      "id": "2",
      "parent_id": "0",
      "name": "name1"
    },
    "3": {
      "id": "3",
      "parent_id": "0",
      "name": "name2",
      "childrens": {
        "9": {
          "id": "9",
          "parent_id": "3",
          "name": "name3"
        }
      }
    },
    "11":{
      "id": "11",
      "parent_id": "0",
      "name": "name4",
      "childrens": {
        "16": {
          "id": "16",
          "parent_id": "11",
          "name": "name5",
          "childrens": {
            "21": {
              "id": "21",
              "parent_id": "16",
              "name": "name6",
              "childrens": {
                "23": {
                  "id": "23",
                  "parent_id": "21",
                  "name": "name7"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    } 
}
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: `const haveChild = ({ id, childrens = [] }, q) => id === q || childrens.some(c => haveChild(c, q))`. ensure you call it on a single node. if you're using the data in the question, wrap it in a single node `{ id: "root", parent: null, childrens: ... }` where `...` is your data.

Comment: i would like to display it in html like a tree structure

Comment: i would actually like to just display the parent_id 0 then on event (can be click or mouseover) display the childrens elements if exist of the clicked ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that the first time you call the function, in the for loop, `key` is the key of every object and `value` the corresponding value

But from the second time `key` is the name of the attribute and `value` the value of the attribute
So you have to create another object in this way:

`{[k]: v}`

I also move the `console.log` outside the inner for loop

```js
const haveChild = (obj, parent_id=0) =>{
        for (const [key,value] of Object.entries(obj)){
            if (value && typeof value === "object"){
                if (value.childrens){
                    for (const [k,v] of Object.entries(value.childrens)){
                        haveChild({[k]: v},v.parent_id)
                    }
                }
                console.log('-----',value.name,'parent id= ',value.parent_id);
            }
       }
}
```

Comment: this sure does something but in a particular order if i may say
```
----- name1 id= 2 parent id=  0
 ----- name3 id= 9 parent id=  3
 ----- name2 id= 3 parent id=  0
----- name7 id= 23 parent id=  21
 ----- name6 id= 21 parent id=  16
----- name5 id= 16 parent id=  11
 ----- name4 id= 11 parent id=  0
```

i would have prefer id2 then no child id3 have a child so go in then next

Comment: This print the children first, and then the parents

If you want the parents first, just move the console.log before the if(value.childrens)

Comment: oh ok yeah any tips on how i could display it in html ?

Comment: I'm not expert in that field and I think depends also from the framework you are using (if any), but it's a totally different question... Surely you'll have to use <li> and/or <ul> and maybe you'll have to change the logic of the code, using the function return the value you want, but again, it's a different question